# Why does everyone keep incessantly saying this?

Tags: cipher, wordplay, mystery

Why does everyone keep incessantly saying this in all the chatrooms, ALL THE TIME?!?!

```
If you see cay
```

*If you see cay* then what, noone posts anything after it, are there implied foul language, controversial topics, conspiracy (at this point im so desperate to get to the bottom of it, i'll believe in anything!). Well, I don't know. Maybe its a riddle, maybe it's a metaphor, maybe it's something else entirely like announcing that my nephews arch-miscarried-step-sister that I never know existed walked straight into the building. I don't know! Can anyone provide meaningful insights into this? All support is greatly appreciated, so that you everyone that participates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be a puzzle or a question related to puzzling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF sounds like the letter 'F', 
YOU sounds like the letter 'U', 
SEE sounds like the letter 'C', 
KAY sounds like the letter 'K'.

It's just a way of spelling out 'F-U-C-K' in a more clever way, or in a way that won't get picked up as easily by profanity filters.

Comment: ... I.... just am blow away. I really cannot believe how stupid I was to not realize something this simple...... Is there really any way I can even justify my own ignorance...

Comment: This pun's been around a while. There are some examples [here](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2009/03/if_you_seek_amys_ancestors.html) including this little rhyme which James Joyce used in *Ulysses* (1918-20): "If you see kay. / Tell him he may / See you in tea. / Tell him from me."